# php, check if a key exists, but it can be multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if a key exists in array, but it can be multiple key?
I meant:

```
$a['b'] = 'Im exists!';
var_dump (isset($a['b']));
```

but my case is a but complicated:

```
$a['c'] = 'c';
$a['xxc'] = 'value';
$a[2][4] = 'more complex!';
$a['b']['d']['g'] = 4;
```

at this point, isset() wont work, but neither array_key_exists. Then how to check, if I want to know if [2][4] exists, or ['b']['d']['g'] does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an interesting problem to solve, here you go:

```
function key_exists_recursive($keys, $array)
{
    if(!is_array($keys) or !is_array($array))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(count($keys) > 1)
    {
        return key_exists_recursive(array_slice($keys, 1), $array[$keys[0]]);
    }

    return isset($array[$keys[0]]);
}
```

Usage: `key_exists_recursive(array('c'), $a);`

Answer (score 2):

Could this work for you (recursive function for multi-dimensional arrays)?

```
function array_key_exists_r($needle, $haystack)
{
    $result = array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
    if ($result) return $result;
    foreach ($haystack as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $result = array_key_exists_r($needle, $v);
        }
        if ($result) return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: emmm im not sure this is what I need

Comment: Hmm. could you elaborate further on why this would not work in your case?

Comment: I want something: thisKeyExitst (array('a'), $inMyArray); OR thisKeyExitst (array('b', 'd', 'g'), $inMyArray); and your function expects key as int

Answer (score 0):

isset() should actually work for this.  Try running the following:

```
$a = array();
$a['b']['d']['g'] = 4;

if (isset($a['b']['d']['g']))
{
  print_r('b,d,g exists!');
}

if (!isset($a['1']['2']['3']))
{
  print_r('1,2,3 does not exist!');
}
```

Output:

b,d,g exists!
1,2,3 does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer that:

```
function array_keys_exist($searchForKeys = array(), $inArray) {
    $inArrayKeys = array_keys($inArray);
    return count(array_intersect($searchForKeys, $inArrayKeys)) == count($searchForKeys); 
}
```